# Java Lambda Consumer Compilation behavior

Tags: java, lambda

I wrote this code, however I am not sure why I get the compilation behavior as shown. The final object `dataMap` has been assigned inside the Constructor as it is usually done and Lambdas are lazily evaluated. If I get rid of the final modifier, the code compiles fine.

```
ConsumerTest.java:17: error: variable dataMap might not have been initialized
      dataMap.compute(DataType.EVENS, (k, v) -> {
      ^
ConsumerTest.java:29: error: variable dataMap might not have been initialized
      dataMap.compute(DataType.ODDS, (k, v) -> {
      ^
2 errors
```

The member variable `dataMap` is declared final and is initialized in the Constructor. Why does the compiler fail to recognize this and complain instead?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.IntConsumer;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ConsumerTest {

  enum DataType {
    EVENS,
    ODDS
  }

  private final Map<DataType, Set<Integer>> dataMap;
  private final IntConsumer allConsumers;

  private IntConsumer evenConsumer = e -> {
    if (e % 2 == 0) {
      dataMap.compute(DataType.EVENS, (k, v) -> {
        if (v == null) {
          v = new HashSet<>();
        }
        v.add(e);
        return v;
      });
    }
  };

  private IntConsumer oddConsumer = e -> {
    if (e % 2 != 0) {
      dataMap.compute(DataType.ODDS, (k, v) -> {
        if (v == null) {
          v = new HashSet<>();
        }
        v.add(e);
        return v;
      });
    }
  };

  public ConsumerTest() {
    dataMap = new HashMap<>();
    allConsumers = evenConsumer.andThen(oddConsumer);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConsumerTest main = new ConsumerTest();
    IntStream.range(10, 31).forEach(main.allConsumers);
    System.out.println(main.dataMap);
  }
}
```

Comment: you just need to initialise it, like `private final Map<DataType, Set<Integer>> dataMap = new Map();`

Comment: @AnthonyKong `Map` is an interface and can not be instantiated. You probably mean `new HashMap<>()`

Comment: How about a `HashMap` then? It is your program and at the end of the day only you know what data structure you want to use.

Comment: @AnthonyKong, the dataMap is initialized inside the Constructor below.  The interesting part here is that by removing the final modifier, this works.

Comment: Folks downvoting should care to explain their reason for doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your two lambdas could be using the value of `datamap` before it has been initialized.  At least, that is what the JLS definite assignment rules are saying.

This is what will happen when the `ConsumerTest` object is created:

1. The bare object is allocated.
2. The superclass constructor is called (`Object()`) which does nothing.
3. The instance field declarations are "executed"

   1. `dataMap` ... not initialized
   2. `allConsumers` ... not initialized
   3. `evenConsumer` ... initialized to the value of the first `lambda`
   4. `oddConsumer` ... initialized to the value of the second `lambda`
4. The body of the constructor is executed

   1. `dataMap` is initialized
   2. `allConsumers` is initialized.

The problem is (conceptually) this.  Those lambdas could in theory be passed  anywhere as soon as they have been initialized.  If the recipient decides to use them  *before* the `dataMap` variable has been initialized, then what would the lambdas see?

- If the `dataMap` variable was not `final`, then they would see the default initial value; i.e. `null`.
- In the case where `dataMap` is final, they are not allowed to see anything.  The `dataMap` variable must be definitely assigned before it is used ... since it is `final`.  The JLS is quite particular on this point.

(Try writing *any* code that reads a `final` variable before it is initialized and you will see what I mean.)

In essence, this is just a rather unexpected (though perfectly logical) consequence of the normal Java rules for `final` initialization.

---

I can think of three solutions in this case:

- Don't make the `dataMap` variable `final`.  It doesn't need to be.
- Initialize `dataMap` in its declaration rather than in the constructor.
- Initialize the lambdas inside the constructor, after initializing `dataMap`.  (Ugly ... but it would work.)

Comment: Thanks @Stephen C,  I was thinking that the lambdas here would be lazily evaluated which in this case is happening much later after the Object is created.  From your response `Those lambdas could in theory be passed anywhere as soon as they have been initialized`, this could also mean the lambdas could be invoked/evaluated from within the Constructor as well, in which case the order of where the `dataMap` is initialized would become critical. Since that cannot be guaranteed at compile time, it ends up throwing this error i suppose.